# dplyr group_by doesn't work on a data.frame, but works on another?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's my problem : dplyr group_by doesn't work on a data.frame, but it works well on another. The problematic dataframe is imported from a SPSS file with the package foreign. when I execute that :

```
d_summarised <- d %>%
group_by(group) %>%
summarise(Sex = (sum(d$GENRE == "F", na.rm = TRUE))/sum(!is.na(d$GENRE))) %>%
select(Sex, group)
```

The result is calculated on the whole sample, and not by group (so the result is the same by group, what is not expected).

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  group      Sex
* <fct>      <dbl>
1 group1     0.626
2 group2     0.626
3 group3     0.626
4 group4     0.626
5 group5     0.626
6 NA         0.626
```

But, at the same time, on the same session, with the same packages loaded, this works :

```
dat <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,3,2,1), y=c(15,24,54,65,82,65))
dat %>%
group_by(x) %>%
summarise(mean(y))
```

Here's the result :

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
      x `mean(y)`
* <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1      40  
2     2      53  
3     3      59.5
```

plyr is not loaded, only dplyr. How could that be possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be breaking the grouping with `d$`.  Instead, use the column names and it should work

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
     group_by(group) %>%
     summarise(Sex = (sum(GENRE == "F", na.rm = TRUE))/sum(!is.na(GENRE))) %>%
     select(Sex, group)
```

NOTE: when we use `d$GENRE`, it is selecting the whole column in the dataset and not limiting the elements within the group

In the second case, OP was applying `mean` directly on 'y' instead of `mean(dat$y)`.  In other words, it is not the data structure i.e. data.frame vs tibble, but it is because of extracting the whole column